# Export the value returned from an async/await function in ES6

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, ecmascript-6, fetch

Is it possible to export the value of an await function from an ES6 class? For example, I have a class with a function named `getDetails` which looks like this

```
class Config {
    static async getDetails() {
        let response = await fetch('url/where/details/are')
        let data = await response.json()
        return data;
    }
}

export { Config }
```

When I import this class into another file, and call `User.getDetails()`, whats returned is `Promise {<pending>}`. Is there a way to make the stack wait for a response from the API first?

Comment: It sounds like you want to delay your whole application until the config is ready. Which is reasonable. But you need to explicitly tell JavaScript how to do this. You can `.then()` the promise, or use `await`.

Comment: What do you mean by "wait for a response from the API first?" ? Before `export`?

Comment: It is a special case and possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use `await` in your parent file too?

```
// your async function

const res = await User.getDetails()

// here you have res
```

Alternatively, you can use `.then`

```
User.getDetails()
.then(res => {
    // use res here
})
```

Comment: Unfortunately then I get `Parsing error: Can not use keyword 'await' outside an async function`

Comment: @Dave you can also go with `.then` option

Answer (score 0):

When calling `User.getDetails()`, you need to either use `.then()` or use `await`. Remember – you can only use `await` within an `async` function, so you would either do

```
async myFunction() {
    const data = await User.getDetails();  
}
```

or

```
myFunction() {
    const data = User.getDetails().then(res => {})
}
```